# Most efficient way to get all records that are duplicates to a particular record in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, datatable

I am trying to validate the content an and excel file and I have managed to read its contents to a datatable. I want to loop through each row and determine the duplicate row of each particular row into a list of class Record.

Here is how I intend the user to see the Error:

Rule: Domain and Username must be different

Input Excel/Datatable

```
Domain  Username Details
x       sam1     1234     //row1
x       jack1    4412     //row2
x       sam1     1233     //row3
y       jack1    4442     //row4
z       jason1   5522     //row5
x       sam1     8949     //row6
```

Output in view

Invalid Entries:

```
Row   Domain  Username Details  ErrorMessage
 1    x       sam1     1234     Duplicate row for r3, r6
 3    x       sam1     1233     Duplicate row for r1, r6                       
 6    x       sam1     8949     Duplicate row for r1, r3
```

Valid Entries:

```
Row    Domain  Username Details  
 2      x       jack1    4412 //not duplicate with row4 because different domain
 4      y       jack1    4442 //row4
 5      z       jason1   5522
```

In the code behind I plan to create a List of a class I created which will be used in the view.

```
public class Record
    {
        public long Row { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage{ get; set; }
        public bool IsValid { get;set; }
    }
```

Code Behind:

```
DataTable excelDataTable = ... //read excel into datatable
foreach (DataRow row in excelDataTable.Rows) //loop through each row of the datatable
{
StringBuilder errorStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); //stores string error message because there would be more validations
Record record = new Record() {
Domain = row["Domain"].ToString(),
Username = row["Username "].ToString(),
Details = row["Details"].ToString(),
};

if(most efficient way to determine if row has duplicates which returns bool)
{
    //most efficient way to get the other rows that the current row duplicates
    errorStringBuilder.Append("Duplicate with: "..)//append rows that it duplicates

}
if(errorStringBuilder.Length != 0)
{
   record.ErrorMessage = sb.toString();
   record.IsValid = false;
}
```

}

returned List

```
return new List().Add(
    new Record(){Row=1, Domain=x, Username=sam1, Details=1234, ErrorMessage=Duplicate row for r3, r6,IsValid=false}
    new Record(){Row=2, Domain=x, Username=jack1, Details=4412, ErrorMessage=,IsValid=true}
    new Record(){Row=3, Domain=x, Username=sam1, Details=1233, ErrorMessage=Duplicate row for r3, r6,IsValid=false}
    new Record(){Row=4, Domain=y, Username=jack1, Details=4442, ErrorMessage=,IsValid=true}
    new Record(){Row=5, Domain=z, Username=jason1, Details=5522, ErrorMessage=,IsValid=true}
    new Record(){Row=6, Domain=x, Username=sam1, Details=8949, ErrorMessage=Duplicate row for r3, r6,IsValid=false});
```

Using linq will be fine.  I just want the most efficient way regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the efficient method `Enumerable.GroupBy`:

```
var usernameDomainGroups = excelDataTable.AsEnumerable()
  .Select((r, index) => new { Row = row, RowNumber = index + 1})
  .GroupBy(x => new {UserName = x.Row.Field<string>("Username"), Domain = x.Row.Field<string>("Domain")});
```

In these groups you will find all rows, the duplicate and the unique ones. You could use a loop to process them and to build your record-list. The tricky part is to generate the duplicate informations:

```
foreach (var group in usernameDomainGroups)
{
    bool isValid = !group.Skip(1).Any();
    if (isValid)
        recordList.Add(new Record
        {
            Row = group.First().RowNumber,
            Domain = group.Key.Domain,
            Username = group.Key.UserName,
            Details = group.First().Row.Field<string>("Details"),
            IsValid = true,
            ErrorMessage = null
        });
    else
    {
        // tricky part, if you need further help ask
        // start with group.Select(r => new Record ....
        // then you can use recordList.AddRange(...)
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you meant grouping by Username and Domain, because grouping by Row and Domain doesn't make much sense (row is unique key).